# Windows time runs slow

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, time, vps

I am using VPS from a web hosting provider Godaddy(windows server 2008 r2). In my VPS I found that time was running slow.The windows time clock has noticeably "losing time" as much as 8 to 10 sec within an minute.I can also notice the second hand on the analogue clock ticking longer seconds sporadically between every 5-10 seconds. Support agents informed me that there is no problem with the parent server. But a simple search in Google for "windows time runs slow" shows so many results and all state that it's problem with CMOS battery. But they are assuring that every hardware is proper. So I want to know is there any case which will cause same problem.

Comment: What sort of VPS? Some hosts do tend to time drift sometimes

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I am using it from so many years. i dont know any error of this kind. It was working proper.

Comment: CMOS battery should only cause time loss on power cycles [(ref)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/w32time/archive/2007/10/31/a-tale-of-two-clocks.aspx).  If the system is up, the CMOS battery should not affect the clock.  More likely is that your virtualized server is running slow, while the host is not.  Losing 8 to 10 seconds a minute is pretty extreme, and I have no idea what might cause that.  That's way beyond what would be expected for drift . . . I'd check the system for load as well as checking the events logs.

Comment: If it is a VPS, as in a shared hosting, someone else you share space with might just be using more cycles and be slowing down the system.